# Read Owner Cert Data from .p12 file with PHP

Tags: php, client-certificates, php-openssl

I'm trying to get the owner info of a certificate with PHP.
I have the `.p12` file and when try to read the info with `openssl` `PHP` functions:

```
if (getenv('HTTPS')=='on'){ 
           $cert=$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT']; 
         }else{ 
            $fname = "certname.p12";
            $f = fopen($fname, "r"); 

            $cert = fread($f, filesize($fname)); 
            fclose($f); 
         }  
        $certdata = array();
        $pass = "pass";

        openssl_pkcs12_read($cert, $certdata, $pass);

        print_r($certdata);
```

I obtain three encrypted fields:

```
['cert']
['pkey']
['extracerts']['0']
```

How could read for example email field in plain text?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by:

After

```
 openssl_pkcs12_read($cert, $certdata, $pass);
```

Do

```
 $certdata= openssl_x509_parse($certdata['cert'],0);
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

I have other way to get the cert value

```
if (openssl_pkcs12_read($almacén_cert, $info_cert, $request->password))
    {
        $pkey = $info_cert['pkey'];  //private key
        $cert = $info_cert['cert'];  //public key

        $certdata= openssl_x509_parse($info_cert['cert'],0);

        return  $certdata; // base64_decode($info_cert['extracerts'][0]);


    } else {
        return "Error.";
    }
```

I used this in Laravel